# no such table error : CacheGroups, Caches, Origins, DeletedCacheResources

Tags: facebook, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins

when login through facebook for first time am getting no such table error even if table exist.(It works fine for normal login)

In logcat am getting these errors(for first time alone):

```
SQLiteLog (1) no such table: CacheGroups
SQLiteLog (1) no such table: Caches
SQLiteLog (1) no such table: Origins
SQLiteLog (1) no such table: DeletedCacheResources
```

if I close the app and then reopen it and go through the same process then it just works perfectly.